# How to extract results from asp.net regex.match?

Tags: asp.net, regex

Coming from perl, I'm I bit confused by the asp.net regex classes.

I have a simple pattern I'm trying to match:  "number text number"

My code looks like:

```
     Match results = Regex.Match(mystring, @"(\d+)\s+(Highway|Hwy|Route|Rte)\s+(\d+)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

     foreach (Group g in results.Groups)
     {
        string token = g.Value;
     }
```

The problem is that the groups seems to contain 4 results, not the 3 I would expect - the first is the entire string that gets matched, while the next 3 are what I would expect.

Is there a simple way to directly access my 3 results?

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = Regex.Match("55 Hwy 66", @"(\d+)\s+(Highway|Hwy|Route|Rte)\s+(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups.OfType<Group>().Select((name, index) => new {name, index}).Where(x => x.index > 0).Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

Comment: That does not exclude the item that contains the complete match - I still get 4 items in the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Matches`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx):

```
// Define a test string.        
string text = "The the quick brown fox  fox jumped over the lazy dog dog.";

// Find matches.
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

// Report the number of matches found.
Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}", 
                      matches.Count, 
                      text);

// Report on each match.
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This just returns a single Match in the MatchCollection, which contains the same 4 groups.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a case of how it is designed to work, and it is just a case of ignoring the first match. I do agree that it is a strange implementation and not how I would have expected it to work.

> If the regular expression engine can find a match, the first element of the GroupCollection object returned by the Groups property contains a string that matches the entire regular expression pattern.

Taken from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)

I know this is an old question, but I ended up here through a search confirming my own thoughts and there was no definitive answer.